# Standalone mode, on ISO the detects only recently deployed Builds

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

"In standalone mode, on ISO the detection of new updated version of the build is recognizing only recently deployed builds. If the build is older than 5-10 minutes, the service worker fails to detect the update and serves the old version. I am using 'cacha.manifest', without it, standalone mode fails to cache. The odd part is why it loses sensitivity to updates after a certain time. I am using Firebase for hosting, and this is how my hosting header looks. The issue only occurs in standalone mode.

```js
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/cache.manifest",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
   }
```